# W3C Web Bluetooth "acceptAllDevices: true" does not return all devicies. Why?

Tags: web, bluetooth, w3c

Going by the
Web Bluetooth
Draft Community Group Report, 11 February 2019
https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#example-filter-by-services

and

Web Bluetooth API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API

The following code should return all available bluetooth devices:

```
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices:true}).then(function(device) {
    console.log('Name: ' + device.name);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong. " + error);
});
```

When I refresh my html page I see the display screen with, "http://localhost wants to pair" at the top and some devices I do not know are listed; however, other devices that clearly show up in the Windows 10 "Bluetooth & other devices" info box are not in the Web Bluetooth info box.

I am trying to create the simplest code sample possible.  I am baffled as to why this does not work.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thx!

And yes, Google Chrome is up to date
Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Bluetooth only works with Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE); so devices that are standard Bluetooth may show up in your Windows 10 "Bluetooth & other devices" info box but not in your Web Bluetooth pairing box.

A great way to learn about Web Bluetooth is to study the example code at [Web Bluetooth Samples](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/) and get the [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral) from Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

What are the "other" devices that do not show up? Install the nRF Connect app on a phone or tablet and use it to check. It can be trusted. Does Windows 10 show devices currently in range or advertising or is it showing devices your machine has previously connected to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe devices that show up in Web Bluetooth picker are devices you can connect to on Windows.